# How to use include statement in Fortran 90?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran, fortran77

I have some .h files that are used for some modules in FORTRAN 77 (which I haven't written myself). I want to write a new routine in Fortran 90 and use such .h files. 
I've tried to use `include 'foo.h'`, when I try to compile ( using ifort Version 13.0.0.079 Build 20120731) I get the following error:

`Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'FOO' when expecting one of: ( % [ : . = =>
C     FOO COMMOM`

I've also tried to use `include foo.h`, what gives me the following errors:
`error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'FOO' when expecting one of: <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT>
  INCLUDE FOO.h
----------^`

`error #6274: This statement must not appear in the specification part of a module
  INCLUDE foo.h
--^`

`error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.
!$ use omp_lib
---^`

`error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.
  implicit none
--^`

`error #6456: This name must be a RECORD name.   [FOO]
  INCLUDE FOO.h
----------^`

`error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.   [H]
  INCLUDE foo.h`
-----------------^

`error #6252: This format specifier is invalid.   [FOO]
  INCLUDE foo.h`

I guess `include` doesn't exist in F90. Is there something similar that allows one to use .h files?

Comment: Did you try `include 'foo.h'`?

Comment: Yes I have tried both `include 'foo.h'` and `include foo.h`

Comment: And they both gave you the same error? When including compiler error message in your question, it is always useful to also include compiler name and version.

Comment: @IRO-bot thank you. I've juste edited my question, I'm using ifort

Answer (score 5):

I think you may be mixing the free format program and the fixed format include files. You will have to have both files in the same format, or in the "intersection format" from http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Continuation+lines

Another cause of an error would be using the include statement in the wrong  part of the file. It must be placed in the right place according of the content of the file, i.e. executable code; variable and type definitions (specification expressions) or procedure definitions have all their appropriate place.

Comment: As @VladimirF almost writes: the text of the included file will be spliced into the including file at the line with the `include` statement and the result must then accord with the rules of statement order that Fortran requires.